# explanation required for the logic of a proof step regarding set membership, conjunction, and implication

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

This question is asking for an explanation of a step in the following segment of someone else's proof of a textbook exercise regarding set membership, conjunction and implication.

---

Consider the following:

$$ (x \in A \land y \in B) \implies (x \in C\land y \in D) $$

Let me check I understand the meaning. It says that if **both** $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, then we can conclude that **both** $x \in C$ and $y \in D$. **Both** clauses of the antecedent must be true in order for **both** clauses of the consequent to be true.

The online solution guide then had the following as the next step:

$$ (x\in A \implies x \in C) \land (y \in B \implies y \in D) $$

**Question:** I don't understand how the step was made to this statement. Can anyone explain (for a self-teaching newcomer to maths)?

---

**My Thoughts**

The first statement had pairs of clauses, connected by a conjunction. Both clauses had to be true in the antecedent for the consequent to be true. It so happens the consequent also has paired clauses, connected by a conjunction, but even if it didn't, my concern would still stand.

The second statement seems to have disaggregated the paired clauses, which feels incorrect to me.

I'm trying to translate the second statement into English to see if helps. It says:

> "Both of the following are true:
>
> - $x$ in $A$ implies $x$ in $C$
> - $y$ in $B$ implies $y$ in $D$"

These two statements are independently true. That is, $x \in A \implies x \in C$ is independently true of $y \in B \implies y \in D$.

This is in contrast to the original statement which didn't separate $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ into independent antecedents.

So to me, the step looks wrong.

---

**Update**

I failed to mention that all the sets $A, B, C, D$ are assumed to be non-empty. I didn't think it made a difference. If it does, an explanation would help me understand the original question better.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us the source of this problem, and also linked us to the online solution you speak of.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. The second statement clearly implies the first one, but the converse is false. A counterexample is $B=\varnothing,A\not\subseteq C$.

**Edit after your update:**
this was however essentially the only counterexample, i.e. if $A$ and $B$ are non-empty then
$$\forall x\forall y\quad[(x \in A \land y \in B) \implies (x \in C\land y \in D)]$$
implies
$$\forall x\forall y\quad[(x\in A \implies x \in C) \land (y \in B \implies y \in D)]$$ or equivalently,
$$\exists x\exists y\quad[(x\in A \land x \notin C) \lor (y \in B \land y \notin D)]$$ implies
$$\exists x\exists y\quad[x \in A \land y \in B\land(x \notin C\lor y \notin D)].$$ Indeed, if there exist some $x,y$ such that, for instance, $x\in A \land x \notin C$, then, keeping this $x$ but taking as a new $y$ some element in $B$, you get that $x \in A \land y \in B\land(x \notin C\lor y \notin D)$ holds.

Comment: Thank Anne, but I'm struggling to go from your first statement $\forall x\forall y\quad[(x \in A \land y \in B) \implies (x \in C\land y \in D)]$ to the second $\forall x\forall y\quad[(x\in A \implies x \in C) \land (y \in B \implies y \in D)]$. Is it really obvious to most people? I've been working on it since yesterday and can't find the logic.

Comment: Which step don't you understand in my proof by [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)?

Comment: Thanks Anne. I understand the idea of a contraposition: to prove $A \implies B$ we can show $\neg B \implies \neg A$. I don't understand how the "or equivalently... " formula comes from. Are you using $P \implies Q  \equiv \lnot P \lor Q$?

Comment: I am mainly using precisely what you wrote, applied to $$A\equiv\forall x\forall y\quad[(x \in A \land y \in B) \implies (x \in C\land y \in D)]$$and $$B\equiv\forall x\forall y\quad[(x\in A \implies x \in C) \land (y \in B \implies y \in D)].$$ And indeed, for instance when writing $\neg A$, I use that $$P \implies Q  \equiv \lnot P \lor Q
$$ hence $$\neg(P\implies Q)\equiv P\land\neg Q.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand where your confusion lies. In short, you are not paying attention to the fact that $\,x\,$ and $\,y\,$ are arbitrary. I expound below.

---

To get your answer, first consider a different scenario than yours. Imagine that $\,x=y\,$. In this scenario, your statement would be
$$
\forall x,\qquad x\in A\ \land\ x\in B\ \ \implies\ \ x\in C\ \land\ x\in D\ \ ,
$$
and this **does not** imply that
$$
\forall x,\qquad \left(x\in A \implies x\in C\right)\land\left(x\in B \implies x\in D\right)\ \ .
$$
What is essential to take note of in this scenario is that all the statements are about a single (arbitrary) element $\,x\,$ -- there are no statements about $\,y\,$. Looking at it from a different angle, the implication is in the form
$$
\forall x,\qquad P(x)\ \land\ Q(x)\ \ \implies\ \ M(x)\ \land\ N(x)\ \ ,
$$
where $P$, $Q$, $M$, and $N$ are functions that output `True` if $\,x\,$ is in $\,A$,$B$, $C$, and $D$ respectively, and `False` otherwise. (Look up *predicates* or *indicator functions*.)

---

Now consider the actual scenario you are in. That implication is in the form
$$
\forall x,\forall y,\qquad P(x)\ \land\ Q(y)\ \ \implies\ \ M(x)\ \land\ N(y)\ \ ,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\forall y,\forall x,\qquad P(x)\ \land\ Q(y)\ \ \implies\ \ M(x)\ \land\ N(y)\ \ ;
$$
and the point here is that $\,x\,$ and $\,y\,$ are arbitrary. Knowing something about $\,x\,$ **cannot** tell you anything about $\,y\,$ (trivial statements notwithstanding). So if you know $\,x\in A\,$ you cannot conclude that $\,y\in D\,$ because $y$ is arbitrary -- there are 2 degrees of freedom, if you like.
$$
\forall x,\forall y,\qquad P(x) \rlap{\quad\not}\implies N(y)\ \ ,
$$
where the truth set of $\,P\,$ is nonempty, and if it is the universal set, the truth set of $\,N\,$ is not the universal set.

Analogously,
$$
\forall x,\forall y,\qquad Q(y) \rlap{\quad\not}\implies M(x)\ \ ,
$$
where the truth set of $\,Q\,$ is nonempty, and if it is the universal set, the truth set of $\,M\,$ is not the universal set.

---

Edit:

Perhaps I should also mention the fact that
when a statement, say $\,P\land Q\,$, implies a conjunction of two other statements, the statement must be sufficient for each of those two. So $\,P\land Q\implies M\land N\,$ is equivalent to
$$(P\land Q \implies M)\land(P\land Q \implies  N)\ \ .$$

On the other hand, when a conjunction of two statements is sufficient for a conclusion, either the first statement is sufficient for the conclusion, or the second statement is sufficient. So the above is equivalent to
$$
\big((P \implies M)\lor(Q \implies M)\big) \land \big((P \implies N)\lor(Q \implies N)\big) \ \ .
$$
Given my explanations in the original answer, it should be crystal clear why $\,(P\implies M)\land(Q\implies N)\,$ (Recall that a constantly false statement acts like the identity under disjunction).