# When does $ (A \land B) \implies (C \land D)$ imply $ (A\implies C) \land (B \implies D)$?

Tags: logic

Consider the following logical statement.

$$ (A \land B) \implies (C \land D)$$

**Question:** Under what conditions does the following statement follow from the above?

$$ (A\implies C) \land (B \implies D)$$

---

**Context:** I realised the heart of [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889835) is this simpler to state, more general question.

---

**My Thoughts**

As a beginner, my initial error was to separate $A$ from $B$ in the antecedent of the first statement, and proceed from there. This is an error because the antecedent is only true if $A$ and $B$ are **both** true.

I then tried reading about rules for distributing conjunctions over implications, but that seemed to be a very mechanistic approach, lacking intuition.

My third attempt was to consider that the second statement implies the first fairly easily, but this doesn't seem fruitful in revealing the conditions in which the first implies the second.

Comment: Here is a condition $A\implies \lnot D \and B\implies \not C$

Comment: One condition under which the second statement follows from the first is $\,A\equiv B\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a truth table to draw out the exact cases in which a specific formula holds. It so happens that the implication in question is true precisely when $(A \Rightarrow (B \lor C)) \land (B \Rightarrow (A \lor D)$ is true.

Another common method is to use the laws of Boolean Algebra (or whichever other sound and complete proof system you want) to reduce the formula to a simpler form, e.g. CNF or DNF. The main idea is to use a decision procedure so that you can algorithmically determine the truth conditions for a formula.